# how to get axios.post(`api/ImageUpload`, img_mode) value from $request in laravel controller

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, request

I am totally beginner in Laravel so sir please help me.

I will send `Image_Mode="Gallery"` from
react `axios.post()` and want to fetch `Image_Mode` value in laravel controller.

example:

```
$img_mode = $request->input('img_mode');
```

REACT CODE

fileUploadHandler = (e) =>{
        let img_mode ='';
       const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } , img_mode:this.state.img_mode};

```
    let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", this.state.selectedFile);
    axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ImageUpload`, formData,config,img_mode)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      console.log(res.data);
    })

  }
```

[image: please see the image]

Comment: what  do you get when dd($request->all()); ?

Comment: can you show the js code you use to send the ajax?

Comment: sir i will attach output screen shoot . img_mode:"Gallery" get and i want to use img_mode value in my controller

Comment: fileUploadHandler = (e) =>{
        let img_mode ='';
       const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } , img_mode:this.state.img_mode};
        
        let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", this.state.selectedFile);
        axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ImageUpload`, formData,config,img_mode)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          console.log(res.data);
        })

      }

Answer (score 0):

If you add `formData.append('img_mode', img_mode);` like below, then in your controller code should work from there:

```
   fileUploadHandler = (e) => {
        let img_mode = '';
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            img_mode: this.state.img_mode
        };
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('img_mode', img_mode);
        formData.append("file", this.state.selectedFile);
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ImageUpload', formData,config,img_mode) .then(res => { console.log(res); console.log(res.data); }) 
    };
```

Comment: Sir thank you so much for your support,  how i get img_mode value in controller, i tried this and get 500 error.....  

     
$img_mode=$request->file('img_mode');
$img_modeName = $img_mode->getClientOriginalName();      
return  $img_modeName;